# If $M$ is a 4-dimensional, compact, simply connected manifold with boundary, what is the topology of $\partial M$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology

I know if we have a compact simply connected 3-manifold with boundary, then the boundary will be $S^2$. The argument is as following

1) $H_1(M)\simeq 0$;

2) Poincare duality $H_2(M,\partial M)\simeq H^1(M)\simeq 0$;

3) Long exact sequence we have

$$\to H_2(M,\partial M)\to H_1(\partial M)\to H_1(M)\to$$

Thus $H_1(\partial M)\simeq 0$ and $\partial M\cong S^2$. Now if we do same argument for 4-dimensional compact simply connected manifold with boundary we cannot say anything about 1st and 2nd homology groups, like we could above. I think $\partial M\cong S^3, S^1\times S^2, L(p,q)$, but the argument doesn't work. How can I show this?

Comment: As a note, the boundary can be a disjoint union of copies of $S^2$; it doesn't have to be connected. (Just take $S^3$ and delete a bunch of balls.)

Answer (score 14):

There are many more 3-manifolds that arise as the boundary of compact *contractible* 4-manifolds than just those, including some Brieskorn spheres like $\Sigma(2,3,13)$. The keyword you want is Mazur manifold. It is my impression that, and I would be surprised if it weren't true, there is not much known about what 3-manifolds arise as the boundary of a Mazur manifold.

Now if you just want simply connected, *every* orientable 3-manifold bounds a simply connected 4-manifold. First recall the Lickorish-Wallace theorem that every oriented 3-manifold $M$ arises from surgery on a link in $S^3$. This defines a cobordism $W: S^3 \to M$ that's obtained by attaching 2-handles to $S^3 \times I$; this remains simply connected. Now simply cap off the copy of $S^3$ with a ball. This gives a simply connected 4-manifold that bounds $M$.

(Of course, a non-orientable 3-manifold cannot bound a simply connected 4-manifold. For simple connectedness implies the 4-manifold is orientable; and the boundary of an orientable manifold is orientable.)

Comment: What about if I add symmetry to my manifold with boundary, like $U(1)^2$ symmetry?
Then I know the compact manifold without boundary (By Ramond,OrliK,1972) is $\cong n(S^2\times S^2)\# n(\pm \mathbb{CP}^2)$. Then can I say since any $3D$ closed manifold with $U(1)^2$ action (without discrete isotropy subgroup) is $\cong S^3,S^1\times S^2,L(p,q)$, $\partial M$ is one of these cases.

Comment: If I believe your statement that those are the only 3-manifolds with effective torus action, then yes, that (or the disjoint union of some of those) must be the boundary of a manifold with effective torus action, because we can just restrict our action to the boundary.

Comment: $\Sigma (2,3,5)$ does not arise as the boundary of a smooth contractible 4-manifold as it has nonvanishing Rohklin invariant. The $E_8$-plumbing glued to this contractible 4-manifold on $\Sigma (2,3,5)$ would violate Rohklin's theorem.

Comment: @PVAL: Fixed. ${}$